# TensorFlow: Efficiently calculating sqrt using a boolean_mask

Tags: python, tensorflow

For efficiency I want to calculate the sqrt of a tensor only for values that are below a threshold.

In numpy, for example, I have

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(size=(10e6))
%timeit np.sqrt(x)
-> 10 ms ± 17.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

If I use a mask

```
x_m = x[x < 1e-3]
%timeit np.sqrt(x_m)
-> 8.94 µs ± 20.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The calculation if faster, as expected, as numpy seems to calculate the sqrt only for the elements x < 1e-3.

In Tensorflow, however, I cannot make this work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()
x_tf = tf.constant(x)
%timeit tf.sqrt(x_tf).eval()
-> 314 ms ± 1.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If I now try to use a boolean_mask

```
mask = tf.boolean_mask(x_tf, x_tf < 1e-3)
%timeit tf.sqrt(mask).eval()
-> 341 ms ± 1.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

there is no speed-up like in the numpy version. It seems like the sqrt in Tensorflow is still computed for all values of the original Tensor x_tf.

Is there a way to run operations (like the sqrt) only on the masked values? Or, alternatively, extract a shorter tensor from the masked tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your measures:

- You are not counting the comparison the boolean masking in NumPy.
- You are creating new graph nodes on each timing trial in TensorFlow.

These should be more representative timings:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.random(size=int(10e6))
%timeit np.sqrt(x)
# 20.4 ms ± 581 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.sqrt(x[x < 1e-3])
# 9.96 ms ± 91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session():
    x_tf = tf.constant(x)
    x_tf_sqrt = tf.sqrt(x_tf)
    %timeit x_tf_sqrt.eval()
    # 16.8 ms ± 685 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
    mask = tf.boolean_mask(x_tf, x_tf < 1e-3)
    mask_sqrt = tf.sqrt(mask)
    %timeit mask_sqrt.eval()
    # 103 µs ± 43.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```